# Doctrine ORM indexBy proper usage

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, relational-database

In doctrine (Symfony) I have a 1-n relationship between two entities: a manager owns n businesses.

```
manager_id | business_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
```

I had no problem in setting the relationship but there is something which is not clear to me regarding the index settings

this is my `Manager.orm.yml`

```
Manager:
    //...
    indexes:
       business__index:
          columns: [business_id]

    //...
    manyToOne:
        business:
            targetEntity: Business
            inversedBy: managers
            cascade: ['persist', 'remove']
            orphanRemoval: true
            joinColumn:
                name: business_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
```

And this is my `Business.orm.yml`

```
 Business:
    //...
    oneToMany:
        managers:
            targetEntity: User\ManagerBundle\Entity\Manager
            mappedBy: pharmacyBusiness
            indexBy: business_id # is this correct?
```

The relationship works as well as the constraints behave as I wish. Yet, the index is successfully created.

My only concern is about the clause `indexBy` which works almost whatever value I put in. 
What value should I use? As you can see I gave the `business_id` value (indexed column) but I don't know whether to use `business_id` or `business__index`  (the index name). It works either way but I don't understand what is goin on :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you need `business__index` definition here since it's a foreign key so RDBMS will create an index on this column anyway.

Second thing is the `indexBy` option. I'm not sure if you understand what is it for. This option is used to create an [indexed association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html) in your **entity** (on PHP level). It doesn't really affect DB schema.

In short words, if you want to be able to easily get item from a collection (`managers` in your case), you may want Doctrine to map your managers in a way where some value of each manager is a key in array (`ArrayIterator` actually), so you can get it like `$this->managers[$someId]`.

Since defined field is used as key, it's obvious that you should use a unique one. Usually it's primary key (`Manager::$id` in your case).

Without this you would need to iterate through whole collection to find a manager with a particular id.